# How to setup up A record for GitHub pages for NearlyFreeSpeech.net

Tags: dns

I own the domain **zenstealth.com** and I have decided that the easiest way for me to "do" a blog is via GitHub pages and Jekyll, which is already built-in in GitHub pages. I've done that already, and for now I've already setup a CNAME record so that my GitHub pages repo **zenstealth.github.com** redirects to **blog.zenstealth.com**.

What I want to do is instead of using a sub-domain for the blog, I'd like to make it use the top level domain **zenstealth.com**. The GitHub Pages instructions say to the set an A record to the ip *207.97.227.245*. The problem in NearlyFreeSpeech.NET (let's call it NFSN for short) is that it already already sets A records to files which are hosted directly in NFSN, and I have absolutely no idea on how to override this.

Comment: Can't you just change the A record to point to the GitHub IP address (or add an A record to point to it)? You won't be using the NFS server for file hosting, so it doesn't need to point to NFS any more anyway.

Comment: There are three A records which points to the NFSN servers, and for some reason they can't be changed (as far I know).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the NFS DNS control panel, but if you've been through their [DNS FAQ](http://faq.nearlyfreespeech.net/full/editdns) and still can't find a way to edit the A records, it might be worth filing a support request or posting in their [forum.](https://members.nearlyfreespeech.net/login/forums/) Either that or move the domain to another registrar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an alias for the site set up? This could be keeping you from adding your own A records.

To check this; on your NFS account, navigate to the *sites* tab. Then click on the *short name* of the site whose records you want to set up. This will bring you to the information page for the site. Under the *Site Names & Aliases* heading, you should see both an entry for the NFS subdomain for the site, and another entry for the alias. Remove the alias for the site by clicking *Remove*. You should now be able to set your own A records for the site (from the *domains* tab).

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you (and sorry for the extremely late reply).